# android testing, testproject or real device?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm final testing a project I've been working on. So far, I've tested the app by installing on various virtual & real devices, and user testing all possible outcomes of the functionality.

Going through the release preparation doc, android test project is the method used in the guide.
I've started to write out some test cases but I can't see the benefit, or additional options from using a test project, that I have not already covered in device/user testing.

Am i wrong to just stick with the device/user tests, or is the test project method just a coded version of the tests I've already completed?

Answer (score 0):

The big advantage of unit-tests is that you can run them always after you did some changes in your code.
This way, it is a lot easier to find a bug which breaks already working functionality.